# WCF Service to store data dynamically from XML to Database

Tags: sql, xml, wcf

I'm trying to build a WCF service that gets info from another service via XML. The XML usually has 4 elements ranging from int, string to DateTime. I want to build the service dynamically so that when it gets an XML, it stores it in the Database. I don't want to hardcode the types and element names in the code. If there is a change, I want it to dynamically add it to the database What is the best way of doing this? Is this a good practice? Or should i stick with just using Entity Framework and having a set model for the database and hardcode the element names and types?

Thanks

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, "it depends...".

If the nature of the data you're receiving is that it has no fixed schema, or a schema that changes frequently as a part of its business logic/domain logic, it's a good idea to design a solution to manage that. Storing data whose schema you don't know at design time is a long-running debate on StackOverflow - look for "property bag", "entity attribute value" or EAV to see various questions and answers.

The thing you give up with this approach is - at the web service layer - the ability to check that the data you're receiving meets the agreed interface contract; this in turn helps to avoid all kinds of exciting bugs - what should your system do if it receives invalid XML? Without an agreed schema/dtd, you have to build all kinds of other checks into your code.

At the database level, you usually end up giving up aspects of the relational model (and therefore the power of SQL) to store your data without "traditional" row-and-column relationships. That often makes queries harder, and may sacrifice standards compliance (e.g. by using vendor specific extensions).

If the data changes because of technical reasons - i.e. it's not the nature of the data to change, it's just the technology chain that makes you worry about this - I'd suggest you instead build in the concept of versioning, and have "strongly typed" services/data with different versions. Whilst this seems more work, the benefits of relying on schema validation, the relational database model, and simplicity usually make it a good trade-off...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! I will look at those debates

Answer (score 0):

Put the xml into the database as xml. Many modern databases support XML directly.  If not, just store it as text.

Comment: I need the data in a table structure so that I can query

Comment: If you're using a modern RDMS that supports xml, you can query it!